# Drupal 7. Server sending tpl before main site html

Tags: drupal

When clicking on a specific menu button the server sends out the contents of a tpl file first before sending the primary HTML. This renders the `<div...` above the `<html...` breaking the site.

This only happens when I clear the cache and first visit to the relevant page. If I refresh the page the site works as it should. Further visits work as well. Its just the initial visit after a cache flush this happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a rogue

```
print($menu)
```

Sorted

Comment: What did you want to tell us?

Comment: Looks like it was a typo error. The original question should be flagged as typo. Glad you figured it out.